# Tangent subspace and tangent plane

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

Find the tangent space and the tangent plane to the graf of the function

$$ f(x,y) = e^{xy}$$ 
at the point $(0,0,1)$.

---

In my textbook the tangent space at the point $(x_0,y_0,f(x_0,y_0))$ consists of all the vectors on the form 
$$ (s,t,s \frac {\partial }{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)+t\frac {\partial }{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)), \ s,t\in\mathbb{R}$$
and the tagent plane is given by the set:

$$\text{{$(x_0,y_0,f(x_0,y_0))+(s,t,s \frac {\partial }{\partial x} (x_0,y_0) + t \frac {\partial }{\partial y} (x_0,y_0))|\ s,t\in\mathbb{R}$}}$$

So far I have that: 
$$\frac {\partial }{\partial x} = ye^{xy}, \ \frac {\partial }{\partial y} = xe^{xy}$$
At the point $(0,0,1)$ if we evaluate the points at the partial derivatives have that: $0+0+e$

I am unsure if this is correct and how the computation should be for the tangent space and the tangent plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is fine. It follows from it that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$. Therefore, the tangent plane is $\{(s,t,1)\,|\,s,t\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: But for the tangent space we have that $(s,t,s\cdot 0 + t\cdot 0) = s,t,0)$ ? and for the tangent plane we have $\text{{$(0,0,1) + (s,t,0)$}}$ - why is this equal to $\text{{$(s,t,1)|\ s,t \in \mathbb{R}$}}$ ?

Comment: Just add the two vectors ...

Comment: Just a follow up question to see If I understand it. Lets say it is the function $f(x,y) = ye^{x}$ then we get: $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(0,0) = 0$ and $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}(0,0) = e^0 = 1$ - so the tangent space is $(s,t,s\cdot 0 + t\cdot 1) = s,t,t$ and the tangent plane would then be $\text{{$(0,0,0)+(s,t,t)$}} = \text{{$(s,t,t)|\ s, t \in \mathbb{R}$}}$ ?

Comment: @MartinWinther Yes, you got it right.